# Can I Upgrade Windows Server 2008r2 to Windows Server 8 (Server 2012)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server, windows-server-2012

I have a test machine with Windows Server 2008 r2, can I upgrade it to Windows Server 2012 (AKA Windows Server 8).

Comment: When it is released I am there will be an upgrade path offered.  You will have to of course upgrade to version that offers that said upgrade migration path.

Comment: @Guy, FYI I just successfully upgraded a 2008 R2 Server to 2012 RTM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With all previous release of Windows, there is a clear pattern that you can upgrade one Windows version to the next immediate version directly. E.g. XP--> Vista. Vista--> Win7. Server 2003-->2008. So I believe it is safe to say that you can upgrade server 2008R2 to Windows Server 8 directly.

Comment: I can see that this should work as there is an 'Upgrade' option as well as a 'Custom' in the install.  However, my system did not actually upgrade easily because it need ADPREP first (even though the old Server 2008 RC DC was running properly).